# Jssor Slider count the slides/images

Tags: slider, jssor

I would like to show the slide count like "2 of 14", "3 of 14", ..., on jssor slider (http://www.jssor.com/demos/simple-fade-slideshow.html). (as the slider moves with slides)

Is there a way that i can make this work?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 steps to go,

1. Add static element (where to display index) in 'slides' container.

   ```
   <!-- Slides Container -->
   <div u="slides" ...>
       ...

       <div id="displayIndex" u="any" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; width: 100px; height: 26px;"></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Display index using javascript call.

   ```
       var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

       function DisplayIndex() {
           $("#displayIndex").text(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex() + 1 + " of " + jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount());
       }

       DisplayIndex();
       jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, DisplayIndex);
   ```

See http://www.jssor.com/testcase/slider-display-index.source.html